# Symfony2 - Form Validation Disabled?

Tags: forms, datetime, symfony

Is there any way to disable form validation?

I have problem with datetime field.
I made in JQuery array with datetime data as follow,

```
   $("[name='{{full_name}}[date][year]']").val(year);
   $("[name='{{full_name}}[date][month]']").val(month);
   $("[name='{{full_name}}[date][day]']").val(day);
   $("[name='{{full_name}}[time][hour]']").val(hour);
   $("[name='{{full_name}}[time][minute]']").val(minute);
```

But when I submit the form, I always get wrong value error messages for `datetime` field.

Does anyone already faced the same issue?

I made my own datetime type field because I wanted to make my own look of it. Firstly i made hidden inputs, and 2 visible inputs, like this:

```
<input type="date" value="{{ date_date }}" {{ block('widget_attr') }} class="form-control pull-left" style="width: 30%" placeholder="{{ 'date'|trans({},'app')|capitalize }}" name="TdateDate" />
<input type="time" value="{{ date_time }}" {{ block('widget_attr') }} class="form-control pull-left" style="width: 20%" placeholder="{{ 'time'|trans({},'app')|capitalize }}" name="TdateTime"/>

<input {{ block('widget_attr') }} name="{{full_name}}[date][year]" value="" class="hidden" />
<input {{ block('widget_attr') }} name="{{full_name}}[date][month]" value="" class="hidden"/> 
<input {{ block('widget_attr') }} name="{{full_name}}[date][day]" value="" class="hidden" />
<input {{ block('widget_attr') }} name="{{full_name}}[time][hour]" value="" class="hidden"/> 
<input {{ block('widget_attr') }} name="{{full_name}}[time][minute]" value="" class="hidden" />
```

Then with Javascript i put data from this two visible fields (date and time) to this 5 hidden inputs to make Datetime array type and i want to pass it to the form by name generated form my field in one variable... But form does not accept it.

From this 2 fields i bring data by JQuery script, like this:

```
var year = $("input[name='TdateDate']").val().substr(0, 4);
var month = $("input[name='TdateDate']").val().substr(5, 2);
var day = $("input[name='TdateDate']").val().substr(8, 2) ;           
var hour = $("input[name='TdateTime']").val().substr(0, 2);
var minute = $("input[name='TdateTime']").val().substr(3, 2);
```

This part working fine, i think. I get datetime array passed to my form field but it just cant validate it...

Comment: Maybe your values are just not formatted correctly for the datetime field?
Of course you could just take away the assertion for that specific field, but there is a reason Symfony is complaining about your values.

Can you provide us with the code you are using to generate your JS-date values?

Comment: I gave you know all the code which is important i think...

Comment: I solved this problem. Because i had to add zeros before to show datetime correctly:

           {% set time_hour = value.time.hour|length == 1 ? '0'~value.time.hour : value.time.hour %}
           {% set time_minute = value.time.minute|length == 1 ? '0'~value.time.minute : value.time.minute %}
           {% set date_month = value.date.month|length == 1 ? '0'~value.date.month : value.date.month %}
           {% set date_day = value.date.day|length == 1 ? '0'~value.date.day : value.date.day %}

Comment: Then before passing variables to form we had to use parseInt to delete zeros...

                var day_parsed = parseInt(day)
                var month_parsed = parseInt(month)
                var year_parsed = parseInt(year)
                var hour_parsed = parseInt(hour)
                var minute_parsed = parseInt(minute)